# JAX-B Maven Generating incorrect SOAP Structure Requests (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, maven, soap, jaxb

I've been attempting to get a Spring Boot Application to generate the following SOAP Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:api="http://simpro4.wirelesslogic.com/api/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <api:getAvailableCustomerSolutions>
     <GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest>
       <accountNumbers>
         <item>xxx</item>
       </accountNumbers>
     </GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest>
   </api:getAvailableCustomerSolutions>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And instead when using the following code:

```
public class WirelessLogicClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    private String endpoint = "http://simprosb.wirelesslogic.com/sandbox.php/api/customerV3";

    public GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsResponse getAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest(){
        GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest request = new GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest();

        // request params
        ArrayOfString accountNumbers = new ArrayOfString();
        accountNumbers.getItems().add("xxx");

        // build request
        request.setAccountNumbers(accountNumbers);

        // send request
        return (GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(endpoint, request, new SoapActionCallback("http://simprosb.wirelesslogic.com/sandbox.php/api/customerV3/"));
    }
```

However when the object is marshalled, using wireshark to see the actual XML sent over the wire from the spring application, I end up with the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <api:GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest xmlns:api="http://simpro4.wirelesslogic.com/api/">
            <accountNumbers>
                <item>786708</item>
            </accountNumbers>
        </api:GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The SOAP endpoint is rather fussy, and requires 2 changes to make this work, the namespace `xmlns:api="http://simpro4.wirelesslogic.com/api/"` **HAS** to be in the  element, it will not parse a response without it. Secondly, the body contents need to be wrapped in an `<api:getAvailableCustomerSolutions>`, which I thought that it would have been able to resolve.

I've used a chrome plugin (Boomerang) to test the endpoint without Java, and it generates sensible requests, but I've had no end of trouble trying to get this working in Java.

I don't have to use Jax-ws, I'm open to using anything that has a maven repo; I don't want to use handlers, as this is simply one SOAP operation of many I'd have to do this for, but I'm having the same issue across all the methods I've tried thus far.

The following are the relevant bits from the WSDL:

```
<message name="getAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest">
  <part name="getAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest" type="tns:GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="getAvailableCustomerSolutionsResponse">
  <part name="return" type="tns:GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsResponse"/>
</message>
.....
<operation name="getAvailableCustomerSolutions">
  <input message="tns:getAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest"/>
  <output message="tns:getAvailableCustomerSolutionsResponse"/>
</operation>
.....
<xsd:complexType name="GetAvailableCustomerSolutionsRequest">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="accountNumbers" type="tns:ArrayOfString" nillable="true"/>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
.....
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="item" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Pom.xml

```
<!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <includes>wirelesslogicsandbox.xml</includes>
                </schemaIncludes>-->
                <generatePackage>wirelesslogic.wsdl</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You mentioned Maven generation. What do you generate and how? Please show relevant parts of `pom.xml`.

Comment: good point @lexicore, added.